# How to modify fork () function?

Tags: c, linux, windows, process, operating-system

I am new to operating systems and working on my OS project, I want to know a way through which i can make changes to `fork` function  (a function that creates child process).
I don't know whether `fork` runs on Windows or only on Linux.

I want to make some changes to `fork`, i.e it should print that whether a child process is created or not, for this purpose I somehow needs to get the definition of `fork` function which I am unable to find.

I know that it exists in `<sys/types.h>`, but don't know where.

I someone can gives me a way or only give the `fork` function definition, I 'll be great, further I will update it my self.

Comment: Can't you just use the return value of `fork`?

Comment: I think if you start an "OS project", it is a very ambitious beginning. Maybe you should try to learn to use google, for example for the localisation of unknown system calls in the os docs, etc.

Comment: Here is the kernel source code  http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/fork.c

Comment: @tmp thanku i have it now

Answer (score 5):

You can not modify `fork`. It's a system call (with libc wrapper normally). It's UNIX specific and does not exist in the same form in Windows.

It returns one of 3 possible values:

0) This is returned in the child!

positive number) Child process id is returned in the parent

negative number) Failure to create child, check `errno` for reasons.

Example use:

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (!child_pid) {
    // child goes here
} else if (child_pid > 0) {
    // parent goes here
} else {
    // could not create child
    perror("fork");
    abort();
}
```

Consult [`man 2 fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for more details.

Comment: More precisely, since it is a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) its functionality is implemented inside the kernel.

Comment: The fact that it is a system call **does not** mean it cannot be modified.  Also given that it is typically reached by way of libc - which is typically dynamically linked - there are also easy ways to intercept it.